# Query to transpose a SQL query dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have values in the table which needs to be reprensented in the different format.Can someone please provide pointers

Table

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Column1    date                 Value |
+---------------------------------------+
| US         07-18-2014           1     |
| US         07-19-2014           2     |
| Canada     07-18-2014           3     |
| Canada     07-19-2014           2     |
| France     07-18-2014           4     |
| France     07-19-2014           3     |
| Japan      07-18-2014           5     |
| China      07-18-2014           7     |
| China      07-19-2014           8     |
```

This needs to be transposed into something like this

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|              US      Canada      France  Japan   China     |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| 08-18-2014  1         3           4        5      7        |
| 08-19-2014  2         2           3               8        |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: you need to use pivot, also are the country names fixed , if not then need to use dynamic pivot

Comment: Yes the country names are fixed.Can you suggest a query for such a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT column1,date,value
    FROM  mytable
)t
PIVOT (SUM(value) FOR item
IN ([US],[FRANCE])) AS pvt
```

Comment: Avoid code only answers as it does not help future users seeking the same subject. Please add some details to why does it solve the problem...

Comment: Thanks for highlighting.The solution to the problem is to use PIVOT.I able to tranpose the rows based on the above query.